# How to copy without empty cells from sheet A to sheet B?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have tried everything but not being successful, this is my code to copy from sheet A to sheet B, I don't know what to add to make it work:

```
for row in range(6, 136):
    c = ws.cell(row=row, column=2)
    ws2.cell(row=row-1, column=2, values=c.value)
```

Comment: Typo everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 5 #row to star writing
for row in range(6,137):
    c = ws.cell(row = row, column = 2)

    if c.value is not None:
        ws2.cell(row = n, column = 2 , value = c.value)
        n += 1 #increment to write skiping blank cells
```

Answer (score 0):

The range call is not affective on the spreadsheet

This should get you going?

```
for rows in ws.iter_rows(min_row=6, max_row=136, min_col=2, max_col=2):
```